# Set System.AreaPath and System.IterationPath readonly in TFS

Tags: tfs

How can I set the field read-only "System.AreaPath" within a state (such as "Approved") when I have a certain value in another field ??? I have already set the conditions of "WHEN" but then "System.AreaPath" field I will always remain impossible to set read-only. Thanks Gabriele

Comment: Can you share the code, the XML snippets for the field and the state?

Answer (score 0):

The `READONLY` rule couldn't be used on **system fields** except `System.State` and `System.Reason`. In [this MSDN document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/apply-rule-work-item-field#related-notes), it says:

> System fields are fields which have System.Name reference names, for
>   example System. Title and System.State. TFS restricts customization of
>   these fields.

The System.AreaPath and System.IterationPath are both system fields.

So the READONLY couldn't be used on those 2 field. If you do want them to be readonly, you could set the readonly property to True of System.AreaPath's control.

```
<Control FieldName="System.AreaPath" ReadOnly="True" Type="WorkItemClassificationControl" Label="&amp;Area" LabelPosition="Left"  />
```